# Handling dates prior to 1970 in a repeatable way in MySQL and Python

Tags: python, mysql, sphinx, epoch

In my MySQL database I have dates going back to the mid 1700s which I need to convert somehow to ints in a format similar to Unix time. The value of the int isn't important, so long as I can take a date from either my database or from user input and generate the same int. I need to use MySQL to generate the int on the database side, and python to transform the date from the user.

Normally, the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), would accomplish this in MySQL, but for dates before 1970, it always returns zero.

The [TO_DAYS MySQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days), also could work, but I can't take a date from user input and use Python to create the same values as this function creates in MySQL.

So basically, I need a function like UNIX_TIMESTAMP that works in MySQL and Python for dates between 1700-01-01 and 2100-01-01.

Put another way, this MySQL pseudo-code:

```
select 1700_UNIX_TIME(date) from table;
```

Must equal this Python code:

```
1700_UNIX_TIME(date)
```

Comment: @John Machin, I guess the point is that I need some kind of intermediate format...doesn't matter what the resulting value of the transformation is, so long as I can generate it consistently from a date with both MySQL and Python. Apologies for typos -- long day. I'll try to update the question...

Comment: 2392323748 was a typo for a 6-digit number?

Comment: Just a friendly FYI: The term you're looking for is deterministic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have MySQL here installed, but when I look here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days - I see an example `TO_DAYS('2008-10-07')` returning 733687.

The following Python function returns `datetime(2008,10,7).toordinal()` = 733322, which is 365 less than the MySQL's output.

So take this:

```
from datetime import datetime

query = '2008-10-07'
nbOfDays = datetime.strptime(query, '%Y-%m-%d').toordinal() + 365
```

and it should work for dates between 1700 and 2100.

Comment: Thanks @eumiro for taking a stab at this. Sorry for my poor explanation. My question should be a bit better now.

Comment: Your code is missing an `import` statement, and the required  statement is NOT as a newbie might imagine `import datetime' but 'from datetime import datetime' ... or alternatively, use `import datetime' then `... datetime.datetime.strptime( ...`. Did you expect the OP to fill in the gap(s) correctly?

Comment: Giving the answer to eumiro for being awesome enough to answer not once, but twice -- Once when my question was terrible, and once when it was actually well written.

Answer (score 2):

According to the link that you gave,

```
Given a date date, returns a day number (the number of days since year 0).

mysql> SELECT TO_DAYS(950501);
        -> 728779
mysql> SELECT TO_DAYS('2007-10-07');
        -> 733321
```

Corresponding numbers in Python:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(1995,5,1).toordinal()
728414
>>> datetime.date(2007,10,7).toordinal()
732956
```

So the relationship is : `mySQL_int == Python_int + 365` and you can convert in the other direction by using the `fromordinal` class method:

```
>>> datetime.date.fromordinal(728779 - 365)
datetime.date(1995, 5, 1)
```