# Is there any pythonic way to convert mysql TO_DAYS output into datetime?

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

The output for MySQL function `TO_DAYS('2016-04-01')` is `736420` (number of days since year 0).

Is there any pythonic way to convert `736420` into `datetime` object?

Comment: Looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002660/handling-dates-prior-to-1970-in-a-repeatable-way-in-mysql-and-python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`datetime.fromordinal()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromordinal):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> days = 736420
>>> datetime.fromordinal(days - 365)
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 0, 0)
```

As explained in the documentation, January 1 of year 1 has ordinal 1 (and MySQL starts from year 0), so you need to subtract one year.